# Angular Material - How to check if checkbox is selected in selenium java?

Tags: java, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I want to check if the checkbox is selected or not (in Selenium + JAVA). 
Attached is the code screenshot.
[image]

Note: ***I have tried .isDisplayed(), .isSelected(), .isEnabled(), nothing worked***

Comment: please show us your automation code.  also, what sort of error do you get when "nothing worked"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1** Check the `mat-checkbox` attribute class contains `mat-checkbox-checked`

```
String classAtr = driver
   .findElemet(By.cssSelector("mat-checkbox")).getAttribute("class");

Assert(classAtr.contains("mat-checkbox-checked")).toBe(true);
```

**Option 2** Check the inside checkbox `isSelected()`

```
boolean isSelected = driver
       .findElemet(By.cssSelector("mat-checkbox input.mat-checkbox-input")).isSelected();
Assert(isSelected )).toBe(true)
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you @yong

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript

`boolean isChecked = (boolean) ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].checked", myWebElement);`